# How to compute elapsed time between each row visited

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to compute elapsed time between each click event in SQL server. So basically, when user click on any particular `Etype` from the same `source`, it should compute the elapsed time. The calculation will be done from `StartTime`.

This is for auditing purpose. I am missing IP elapsed Time. When user hits `IP`, it records time in `starttime` in the table and then when he hits `OP`, it captures another `starttime`. But What I want is that which user has spent how much time on each `Etype`.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpLog](
    [EmpId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LoggedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [EType] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [User] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmpId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

| EmpId | LoggedTime | StartTime | Source | EType | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc |
| 2 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | PEn | OP | abc |
| 3 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | PEn | ED | abcd |
| 4 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | HM | Dash | efg |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | Chk | Sup | cde |

Table should be matched with the result
This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(second, previousStartTime, StartTime) as ElapsedTime
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) previousStartTime
        FROM    [dbo].[EmpLog]
        ) q
WHERE   previousStartTime IS NOT NULL
```

And I am getting the below output:

| EmpId | LoggedTime | StartTime | Source | EType | User | Time | ElapseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | 2021-02-2401:15:46.647 | PEn | OP | abc | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | PEn | ED | abc | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | HM | Dash | efg | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | Chk | Sup | cde | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | 2 |

Expected Output should be:

| EmpId | LoggedTime | StartTime | Source | EType | User | ElapseTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:44.647 | PEn | In | abc | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-02-24 01:15:46.647 | 2021-02-2401:15:46.647 | PEn | OP | abc | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:48.647 | PEn | ED | abcd | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:50.647 | HM | Dash | efg | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | 2021-02-24 01:15:52.647 | Chk | Sup | cde | 0 |

Comment: @DaleK, I have included what I tried. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct Partition to get your Elapsed time and use the Absolute values to dipsplay the answer.

**Answer:**

```
  SELECT 
    EmpId
    , LoggedTime
    , [Source]
    , EType
    , [User] 
    , ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second, previousStartTime, StartTime), 0)) AS ElapsedTime
FROM   
    (
    SELECT  *,
            LEAD(StartTime) OVER ( PArtition by [Source], [User] ORDER BY StartTime) 
            AS  previousStartTime
    FROM    [dbo].[EmpLog]
   ) q

 ORDER BY  EmpId
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @RjLearn have a look in to this answer and let me know any support required. :)

Comment: Hi @Gudwlk, We need to consider `Source` and `User`. In the output above, row 3 should be 0. User has not navigated to any page from there. If I see the row 1, the elapsed time is fine as the same `user` and the `source` between row 1 and row 2. Again, between row 2 and row3, the same `user` and same `source`, so the output 2. But between row 3 and row 4, user and source both are different. so the elapsed time should 0.

Comment: @RjLearn Please refer to your question. in the question it has a section as Expected result which shows the same. Please correct the expected output so we can have a try.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have corrected the expected output. If the user is different even the source is same then it should return 0. If both user and source are same then compute the value.

Comment: @RjLearn Here is your query and result. Hope you have the answer now :)

Comment: @RjLearn I edited your question and changed the 3rd row User name as it should be matched with the result that you have added.  Hope you can find your answer here. if so please mark my answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

…

> So basically, when user click on any particular Etype **from the same source**,

…but if source is not of importance, just remove it from the over() clause:

```
--duration of each type entry..
-- makes sense..but conflicts with expected results
select *,
   isnull(datediff(millisecond, [StartTime], lead([StartTime]) over(partition by [User], [Source] order by [StartTime])), 0) as duration_ms
from [dbo].[EmpLog];



--mixed, duration, elapsed time from previous entry
-- ..a bit conflicting..returns the expected
select *,
   isnull(
   datediff(millisecond, isnull(prvStartTime, StartTime), case when prvStartTime is null then nxtStartTime else StartTime end)
   , 0) as elapsed_ms,
   isnull(abs(datediff(millisecond, isnull(prvStartTime, nxtStartTime), StartTime)), 0) as elapsed_ms2
from
(
select *,
       lag([StartTime]) over(partition by [User], [Source] order by [StartTime]) as prvStartTime,
       lead([StartTime]) over(partition by [User], [Source] order by [StartTime]) as nxtStartTime
from [dbo].[EmpLog]
--where StartTime is not null
) as el
```

..

```
select *,
   datediff(millisecond, lag([StartTime]) over(partition by [User], [Source] order by [StartTime]), [StartTime]) as elapsed_ms
from [dbo].[EmpLog];
```

Comment: I am getting only one record from your query. I want elapsed time based on each `Etype` visited based on `User`.

Comment: ..@RjLearn, it would be extremely helpful if you added the expected results in the description/question.

Comment: Hi @lptr, I have added expected output in the question. The elapseTime should be a difference between 2 rows startTime for that particular user. It will tell that the user has spend this many seconds on this `Etype`. Again If you see the row number 4 and 5. It is `0` because that user has not visited anywhere. So the condition should be the same user and the same datetime.

Comment: ..@RjLearn .. if the expected elapsedtime for empid=3 was 0 [because user=abc didn’t visit anything afterwards], then a simple lead() would give the duration of each Etype (assuming duration is from current row starttime till next row starttime for the same user&[source]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're measuring the time between an event and the next occurrence of another event.  You could use the `LEAD` function.  I think you're looking for something like this

```
select isnull(datediff(second, StartTime,
                       lead(StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime)), 0) as ElapsedTime
from [MCP_Audit].[dbo].[AuditLog];
```